# converting a "2 yrs 2 mon" string to total months

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can this [DataFrame] data be converted as months, ex: 2 yrs 2 mon as 26

```
0     0yrs 0mon
1     2yrs 6mon
2     0yrs 0mon
3     0yrs 0mon
4     3yrs 1mon
5    15yrs 2mon
6    1yrs 10mon
7     0yrs 0mon
8     0yrs 0mon
9    3yrs 10mon
Name: CREDIT.HISTORY.LENGTH, dtype: object
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) command taking advantage of multiplication by a Series:

```
df['MONTHS'] = (df['CREDIT.HISTORY.LENGTH']
 .str.extract(r'(\d+)yrs\s*(\d+)mon').astype(int)
 .mul(pd.Series({0: 12, 1: 1})) # multiply years by 12, leave months unchanged
 .sum(axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
  CREDIT.HISTORY.LENGTH  MONTHS
0             0yrs 0mon       0
1             2yrs 6mon      30
2             0yrs 0mon       0
3             0yrs 0mon       0
4             3yrs 1mon      37
5            15yrs 2mon     182
6            1yrs 10mon      22
7             0yrs 0mon       0
8             0yrs 0mon       0
9            3yrs 10mon      46
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for numbers before `yrs` and `mon`, convert to integers and then create new column:

```
y = data["CREDIT.HISTORY.LENGTH"].str.extract("(\d+)yrs", expand=False).astype(int)
m = data["CREDIT.HISTORY.LENGTH"].str.extract("(\d+)mon", expand=False).astype(int)
data["MONTHS"] = y * 12 + m
    
print (data)
  CREDIT.HISTORY.LENGTH  MONTHS
0             0yrs 0mon       0
1             2yrs 6mon      30
2             0yrs 0mon       0
3             0yrs 0mon       0
4             3yrs 1mon      37
5            15yrs 2mon     182
6            1yrs 10mon      22
7             0yrs 0mon       0
8             0yrs 0mon       0
9            3yrs 10mon      46
```